# Using np.where to find element from sub-arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find all elements in array X that match element on array Y using np.where() and the condition on where() function is comparing list (a) not one element. Please see the following code:

```
X = np.array([[0, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [5, 9], [6, 7], [4, 6]])
Y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5])
a = [2, 3, 4]
matchedX = X[np.where(Y == a)]
```

I am expecting to get the result like this:

```
array([[2, 1],
   [1, 3],
   [5, 9],
   [6, 7]])
```

but I got different results:

```
array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int64)
```

So, I need an alternative solution in a way that I can get the same elements if I do not know about the values of a? This line below give me the exact results that I want, but I do not know in previous the a values.

```
matchedX = X[np.where((Y == 2) | (Y==3) | (Y==4))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the set functions of numpy:

```
X[np.where(np.isin(Y, a))]

array([[2, 1],
       [1, 3],
       [5, 9],
       [6, 7]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the `np.where`, which is redundant here, and just index using [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
X[np.isin(Y,a)]

array([[2, 1],
       [1, 3],
       [5, 9],
       [6, 7]])
```

This is because `np.isin` gives you a boolean array of where `Y` is in `a`:

```
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

So by indexing with this array, it only selects those rows where `True`